# read the post related particular tags and comments in yii

Tags: yii

I have POST table with column 
id, title, content, tags, status, create_time, update_time, author_id, image

I have created modules and models relation in Post model:

```
 return array(
        'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'author_id'),
        'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'post_id', 'condition'=>'comments.status='.Comment::STATUS_APPROVED, 'order'=>'comments.create_time DESC'),
        'commentCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Comment', 'post_id', 'condition'=>'status='.Comment::STATUS_APPROVED),
    );
```

Controller action:

```
public function actionHome()
{        
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
        'condition'=>'status='.Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
        'order'=>'update_time DESC',
        'with'=>'commentCount',
    ));                        
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('tags','home');  // $_GET['tag']);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
        'pagination'=>array(   
            'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['postsPerPage'],
        ),
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));

    $this->render('home',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider
    ));
}
```

home view:

```
<?php foreach($dataProvider as $post) { ?>     

        <div class="blog_wrap">
        <h2> <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($post->title), $post->url); ?></h2>

        <?php if($post->image != '') { ?>
        <div class="img-box"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/post/'.$post->image; ?>"> </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <p><?php echo $post->content; ?></p>

        <a href="more.php">Read More [+]</a> 
        </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Errors:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

at

```
 <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->title), $data->url); ?>
```

How to query the relation table with yii Active record. Mine is not working in home action of controller.

Comment: First of all, the "home view" snippet and the "at" snippet are not the same -- please decide which of the two your code is. Second, you are not passing in `$post`/`$data` to the view, so how do you expect `$post->title` to work?

Comment: sorry  I have used `<?php foreach($dataProvider as $post) { ?> `

Comment: It should be `$dataProvider->getData() as $post` ([documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider)).